# How to make a call to Firestore using gRPC

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, elixir, grpc

I'm trying to build a gRPC client for Google's Firestore API in Elixir.

Before starting to write some code , I thought that it would be wise to first start with BloomRPC in order to debug the issue.

[image]

As base url, I'm using https://firestore.googleapis.com where I pinned the rot certificate.

As auth I'm using an access_token obtained using oauth with the following 2 scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"
being passed as a Authorization header:

```
{
    "Authorization": "Bearer 29ya.a0AfH6SMBDYZPsVgQv0PMqyGRXypc3DfWF_2jbvAJKMquTaryCvxEB7X1Rbprfk1Ebrwid2bXbcR3Aw-d1Tytlo_lThkyqRDRIbnSz5-nQ3xWklkmjyFMAuQtFCoz01hk3vbgBwd2gdbFNNWiOU_8NqPC_vElyz2-cQ34"
}
```

And I get back:

```
{
  "error": "3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Missing required project ID."
}
```

So clearly I should be passing the project ID somehow but I can't find it anywhere in the docs. Anybody any clues?

Comment: Could you please share the code of how you are passing the headers or thr request you are making? Please also check this another [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444009/8791788)

Comment: I'm using BloomRPC to make the call, just so that I can test it first. Just updated the question

Comment: I get the feeling that the JWT token I'm using should be encoding what the projectID is. Can anybody confirm that?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by the that the JWT token you are using should be encoding what the Project ID is ?

Comment: Using a JWT token, it is possible to encode some payload in the token.

Currently I use the Oauth2 sandbox tool from google to generate a JWT token but I that I need to generate one in another manner so that I can specify the projectId in the payload of the JWT token.

Comment: Please have a look into this similar post in [Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090338/firebase-admin-nodejs-cannot-verify-auth-token-jwt). You can specify the project ID as following:

{
 "parent": "Hello",
 "aud": "PROJECT_ID",
 "page_size": 10,
 "page_token: "hello"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong.

Basically the `Bearer` token I was using is correct (obtained via the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)).

The trick was to specify the PROJECT_ID in the `parent` parameter of the request:

```
{
  "parent": "projects/[project-id]/databases/(default)/documents",
  "page_size": 10
}
```

I should have just read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#google.firestore.v1.ListDocumentsRequest) properly :)